# JSON data not showing Ajax inside Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

below code is about me trying to get data from database. The first Ajax shows data successfully, but the second (Ajax request inside the first Ajax) shows nothing.

More explanation:

1. The first Ajax requests data by onchange (working)
2. The second (inside success function) requests another data but never delivered to the view

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

   $('#idclient').change(function(){
       var client=$(this).val();
       $.ajax({
           url : "<?php echo base_url();?>Skejuler/get_dclient",
           method : "POST",
           data : {clients: client},
           async : false,
           dataType : 'json',
           success: function(data){
               console.log(data);

   $.ajax({
       url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>Skejuler/get_lastprob',
       method : "POST",
       data : {clients: client},
       async: false,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
           var dbkosong = 'Belum ada problem';
           var DLP = '';
           var i;
           for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
               DLP += data[i].catprobc+' : '+data[i].action+' oleh '+data[i].hero+' pada '+data[i].created_at; //**is this line any wrong?**
           }
           if (!data) { $('.showLP').html(dbkosong); }
           else { $('.showLP').html(DLP); }
           },
           error: function(){
           alert('Database kosong!');
           }
   });

               var html = '';
               var i;
               for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                   html += '<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">'+
                   '<table class="table table-hover">'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<th>ID</th>'+
                   '<th>'+data[i].client+'</th>'+
                   '</tr>'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<td>MONITORING</td>'+
                   '<td>'+data[i].moni+'</td>'+
                   '</tr>'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<td>IPPBX</td>'+
                   '<td>'+data[i].ippbx+'</td>'+
                   '</tr>'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<td>DATABASE</td>'+
                   '<td>'+data[i].ipdb+'</td>'+
                   '</tr>'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<td>MULTIMEDIA</td>'+
                   '<td>'+data[i].ipmm+'</td>'+
                   '</tr>'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<td>RECORDING</td>'+
                   '<td>'+data[i].iprec+'</td>'+
                   '</tr>'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<td>FXO</td>'+
                   '<td>'+data[i].ipfxo+'</td>'+
                   '</tr>'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<td>VM</td>'+
                   '<td>'+data[i].ipvm+'</td>'+
                   '</tr>'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<td>LOKASI ACD</td>'+
                   '<td>'+data[i].acd+'</td>'+
                   '</tr>'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<td>CALL CENTER</td>'+
                   '<td>'+data[i].callcenter+'</td>'+
                   '</tr>'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<td>PROB TERAKHIR</td>'+
                   '<td><span class="showLP"></span></td>'+ //**Here I'm trying to show the data from database by attr CLASS: showLP, but nothing**
                   '</tr>'+
                   '<tr>'+
                   '<td>STAT</td>'+
                   '<td>'+data[i].stat+'</td>'+
                   '</tr>'+
                   '</table></div>'
                   ;
               }
               $('.cclient').html(html);

           }
       });
   });

   });
   ```

My Controller:

```
    function get_lastprob(){
    $client=$this->input->post('clients');
    $result=$this->skejuler_m->get_lastprob($client);
    echo json_encode($result);
}

function get_dclient(){
    $client=$this->input->post('clients');
    $result=$this->skejuler_m->get_dclient($client);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

My View:

```
<select name="nameclient" id="idclient" class="form-control">
                        <?php $issetotslm = $_REQUEST["nameclient"]; ?>
                        <option value="" selected="selected">^^CLIENT^^</option>
                        <?php foreach($clients as $row) { echo '<option value="'.$row->client.'">'.$row->client.'</option>'; } ?>
                    </select>
```

I can see the JSON data by inspecting in browser, but what I am doing wrong / missing in the script? Please help...

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `.val()` or `.text()` instead `html()`, if yes what went wrong?

Comment: I think this will answer your question. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/118772/execute-one-ajax-request-after-another-ajax-request-finished

Comment: @YashKaranke Tried. But still not working. Thanks

Comment: i don't see any reason for a stacked ajax call here - just combine the output of `get_dclient` and `get_lastprob` into one function ...

Comment: hi can i see your controller, Make your life easy don't send json back, send data from controller to view create html there and than return back to your ajax response.

Comment: Could you try replacing : `'<td><span class="showLP"></span></td>'+` with  `'<td><span class="showLP">'+(DLP ? DLP : dbkosong)+'</span></td>'+` ?

Comment: @sintakonte The first ajax / `get_dclient` gets data from table1 (contain column named _client_). The second ajax calls data where client=$client (stored as form data) from table2

Comment: @umefarooq Thank you in advance. I just added my controller and view in my Question.

Comment: @HastaDhana Replaced. And got error "ReferenceError: DLP is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

The second ajax never got var `client` cause its scope ended at the first ajax call and to fix that you need to make it global var:

```
var client;

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#idclient').change(function(){
    client=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo base_url();?>Skejuler/get_dclient",
        method : "POST",
        data : {clients: client},
        async : false,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>Skejuler/get_lastprob',
                method : "POST",
                data : {clients: client},
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, both first and second Ajax has their vars stored as var: clients (with s) after executing Onchange function (first Ajax). Also tried adding the global var and still nothing.

Is this stacked Ajax (the logic and the method) right? Is there another better way?

Answer (score 0):

as I am new in coding and just learned about how *async: false* working, I just uncommented it for the second Ajax. And it works!

Here is the updated on the second Ajax (inside):

```
$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>Skejuler/get_lastprob',
method : "POST",
data : {clients: client},
//async: false,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
    var dbkosong = 'Belum ada problem';
    var DLP = '';
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        DLP += data[i].catprob+' : '+data[i].action+' oleh '+data[i].hero+' pada '+data[i].created_at;
    }
    if (!data) { $('.showLP').html(dbkosong); }
    else { $('.showLP').html(DLP); }
    },
    error: function(){
    alert('Database kosong!');
    }
});
```

But, I need to know that way / logic I get the data by a stacked Ajax is good in performance. If anyone has another better way, please share it.. Thank you